# Copy widgets from one xib to other along with the IBOutlets and IBAction

Tags: ios, xib, ibaction, iboutlet

I have 4-5 XIB's, and they have a common bottom bar having 4 UIButton's.

I am able to select them, and copy them for one XIB to other, but is there a way to also copy the IBOutlet's and IBAction's corresponding to those widgets?

Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks